# Magento 1.4.1.1 - Search not working, Cross-Sell, New Products on Home Page, Up-Sell, Related Products Not working

Tags: php, mysql, database, magento

Using 1.4.1.1

I’ve recently changed some php code in header.phtml to align my navigation titles so the wording appears on top of each other.
 After I did this I also changed the organization of the categories within the back end under Catalog > Category Management. none of the Cross-Sells, Up-Sells, Related products or New Products on the Home Page are showing up along with the sarch.

I’m not sure if changing the header.phtml is related to these options not working. I don’t see how changing the header.phtml could render those options useless.

The only other things i’ve done since i’ve changed that code was create a sitemap, and a new robot.txt file which should have no effect on the website and change the order of the navigation items up top....meaning, instead of “Navigation Category 4” being in the fourth spot, I put it in the 1 slot then moved it back to the four slot within the back end under Catalog > Manage Categories for a split second… I dragged and dropped them into a new location, but then moved them back to how those two categories were organized before. I also changed the name of an existing category.

yes… i’m sure that all products are instock, with quantity available. All these things (cross-sells, up-sells, new products, etc) were working yesterday so I know they are set up correctly. It seems like something I did changed the file that controls all of those options.  I’ve also re-indexed and re-cached everything.

Does anyone have any advice on where to look or what may have changed? All the XML is still set up correctly under CMS > Pages > Home Page. It still shows XML there to call out the new products on the home page but there not displaying. I have a feeling once I fix the home page issue with not displaying new products, that the others will be fixed to.

Please remember that these options were working yesterday. Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

P

P.S. I’ve also realized now that searching is not working on the website. I’ve re-indexed everything and it’s not working. The only thing not re-indexing is “Category Products” but that has always said “processing” and won’t re-index. So I dont know why that would now mess anything up. This is seriously killing me. Corrupt DB? I've tried to repair the db but cannot upload large .sql dumps via MYphpAdmin, and don't have shell access.

I will seriously send money to someone who can cure these issues. I'm a man of my word.

Thank you everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Erase everything in `/var/locks/` and re-index.

Comment: Do this as a first step to get past that indexing issue.  If it doesn't fix it then there's other things to check.

Comment: I did try that. I erased everything in locks, sessions and cache. But I will try it again and see if it works. Fingers crossed.

Comment: Someone else mentioned that PHP max execution time may need to be raised by Rackspace... however... Everything else worked before so not sure if that could be an underlying cause of all the issues.

Comment: Well it actually says permission denied now on FileZilla when trying to delete the locks... strange...

Comment: Do you have root access to your server?  If not, then ask Rackspace to delete all the files in `YOUR WEB ROOT/var/locks/`

Comment: PHP timeouts could cause the indexing to end prematurely which could cause problems.  How many SKUs do you have?

Comment: I have root access. I've deleted those before which is strange. I have 5900 sku's.

Comment: Could it have something to do with the owner/group shows apache apache for the locks files but when I export stuff like prodcuts it displays owner as 'ERP' which is what i log in as? Would that be why I cannot delete locks? I believe that's why Magento Connect hasn't worked. Because the name is different then what's in apache, but that's over my head also and I haven't had to use Magento Connect so I brushed it off.

Comment: If you have root access then it doesn't matter what the permissions are.  You should be able to delete the lock files.   If you have SSH access then you can login at the command line to change the owner.  If you are unsure how to do that then you should ask Rackspace to do it for you to avoid any problems.  Bring up to them that you can't delete those files and see if they'll fix the permission issue for you.

Comment: Sean,
I'd like to thank you for your continued help and support. I'll have a talk with them to see what the issue is.
Thank you again.